# can't launch android emulator while logged in over vnc?

Tags: arch-linux, kvm, vnc, qemu

i have a headless box running bbqlinux that i'm trying to use as an android-studio development box. when i go to launch an .avd in the emulator, i receive this error:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator
Output: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: This user doesn't have permissions to use KVM (/dev/kvm).
```

this was freaking me out and i spent a good amount of time trying to sure that everything was enabled, installed correctly, permissions set, etc... then: i plugged a screen in and logged directly into the box and bam! it works fine.

so my problem is maybe the vncserver? i'm using `tigervnc` that i set up according to this page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vncserver

just in case it helps, my `xstartup` file is

```
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
startxfce4 &
```

other than that, i've not changed the default environment hardly at all except to add lighttable, ssh, & vnc. so my question is really

- should i not be doing it this way? is there a better workflow or vnc server program for what i'm trying to do?
- is there a command switch or option that i missed that maybe enables the hardware acceleration over vnc?

thanks!

Comment: When I tried running the emulator inside vnc it failed, I can't remember the exact reason why it failed - but I have a vague recollection of it being that VNC does not have native support for XRANDR.

Comment: Also if memory serves I got more information from `adb logcat`

Comment: huh. i haven't heard of `xrandr` before, but a quick search seems to show that at least `tigervnc` should support it. also `adb logcat` won't show me any data since the emulator never actually starts.

Answer (score 0):

in the end, i *pretty much* got it running by using nomachine. here's what i did:

1. download the current `.tar.gz` from [nomachine.com](https://www.nomachine.com/download/linux&id=1)
2. `cd /usr`
3. `sudo tar xvzf nomachine*.tar.gz`
4. `sudo /usr/NX/nxserver --install fedora` <-- adding fedora here overrides the "linux is not a supported operating system" message.
5. `sudo /usr/NX/scripts/vgl/vglserver_config -config +s +t +f`
6. in `/usr/NX/etc/node.cfg` set `EnableVirtualGLSupport 1`
7. reboot
8. panic a little because now (a) my client's nomachine won't acknowledge the server's desktop and (b) the server's desktop won't load on startup. if i run `startx` i receive an error message about mate-session, which i'm not even using.
9. in `~/.xinitrc` i set `DEFAULT_SESSION=startxfce4`.
10. reboot
11. the desktop comes up fine, but when i connect from the client i receive this error from nomachine "no available sessions on this server".
12. `sudo /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --restart`

and now it works. the emulator comes up and is highly responsive (yay!).

after rebooting a couple times, i'm having these issues:

- the desktop doesn't start and i have to run `startx` from the local terminal on the server. that's annoying if i'm remote.
- i have to restart the nxserver 2 out of 3 times that i reboot.
- when i'm remoted in, the local desktop is open - so i need to put the mouse & keyboard under the desk so people don't accidentally type into my session. also if you turn on the monitor you can see what i'm doing. (or see what i'm **not** doing, which is probably worse, ha!)

i hope this helps someone!